# What is the function execution order?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

Please keep in mind that I'm of a VB background and switching to C#.

In this code I'm simply using functions to insert data into db, send an email confirmation, and lastly reset all form fields.  However an exception is generated due to the ResetForm function clearing the the email address field that is referenced by the the SendEmail function.

Shouldn't the SendEmail function execute completely before ResetForm even starts? Am I missing something here?  The code works if I comment the line that clears the emailaddress textbox.

The info from trace:

"There was an error:  The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: address"

```
    protected void btnSendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            InsertRecords();
            SendEmail();

            //If both insert records and send email are successful, clear the form and session variables
            ResetForm();
            confirmation.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.Warn("There was an error:  " + ex.Message);
        }

     }

    protected void SendEmail()
    {
        DataTable tblStudents = (DataTable)Session["tblstudents"];

        string strSenderEmailAddress = txtEmail.Text;

        MailMessage emlMessage = new MailMessage();
        emlMessage.From = new MailAddress(strSenderEmailAddress);

        emlMessage.To.Add("someaddress@somewhere.com");

        emlMessage.Subject = "Some subject";
        string strMessageBody = "Some wonderful message";
        string strStudentInfo=null;
        foreach (DataRow row in tblStudents.Rows)
        {
            strStudentInfo = strStudentInfo
                + row["firstname"].ToString() + " " + row["middlename"].ToString() + " " + row["lastname"].ToString() + " DOB:  " + row["dob"].ToString() + " " + row["school"].ToString()
                + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        string strMessageFooter = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine

            + "Some info about organization";

        emlMessage.Body = strMessageBody + strStudentInfo + strMessageFooter;

        SmtpClient myClient = new SmtpClient("smtphost");
        myClient.Send(emlMessage);

    }
```

Error info:

```
Line 197:
Line 198:            MailMessage emlMessage = new MailMessage();
Line 199:            emlMessage.From = new MailAddress(strSenderEmailAddress);
Line 200:            //emlMessage.To.Add("someone@else.me");
Line 201:            emlMessage.To.Add("email@email.com");


Source File: c:\Users\igainey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects    \parentportalsignup    \parentportalsignup\default.aspx.cs    Line: 199

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: address]

   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding     displayNameEncoding) +1475149

   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address) +8

   parentportalsignup._default.SendEmail() in c:\Users\igainey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\parentportalsignup\parentportalsignup\default.aspx.cs:199

   parentportalsignup._default.btnSendRequest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\igainey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\parentportalsignup\parentportalsignup\default.aspx.cs:240

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9752554

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +196

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10

   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String     eventArgument) +13

   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35

   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: "Shouldn't the SendEmail function execute completely before ResetForm even starts?" Yes it should - run it in the debugger and make sure something else isn't clearing out the form.

Comment: Could you show the code of `SendEmail`? As you describe it, there should be some multithreading activity.

Comment: Please give us the details of the exception: Type, Message, and StackTrace.

Comment: Have in mind that the `Page_Load` event will execute first, then the `btnSendRequest_Click` event. Make sure something else is not clearing the fields in the page's load (in which case, use !Page.IsPostBack).

Comment: _"an exception is generated due to the ResetForm function clearing the the email address field"_ What exception? Also, where is this exception raised exactly? Look at the stacktrace or even better - use the debugger.

Comment: Let us see `SendEmail`. Are you sure you're not using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendAsync(...)`?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil That was my first thought as well

Comment: @DanielMann - Great minds think alike :P.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil is not `SendAsync` collect all required parameters before it returns? it must be something else...

Comment: I've added the SendEmail code and trace info as requested.

Comment: @IanGainey Attach a debugger. If `txtEmail.Text` is null, that's your problem -- it's not being persisted across postbacks. It could be an issue with the viewstate.

Comment: You should check for null values and also make the SendEmail function return a boolean if successful or not, before resetting the fields. That will assure your reset function only runs if email is sent successfully.

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic.  txtEmail.txt has a value for sure.  It's set as a value of the text attribute.  How can the text value be null before it's changed in the ResetForm function?

Comment: Solved.  ResetForm function was being called in a separate location.  That's what I get for not being explicit in naming.  ResetForm() was being called instead of correctly calling ResetFormStudent(). I thought this was some sort of C# behavior that I wasn't accustomed to. I'm sorry to have wasted everyone's time.